# How to Import C function from R package to use in mine?

Tags: c, r, r-package

I'm building a package that uses a C function located in `src` in other package (`npcp` package). That function is inside folder: `utilities.c` and there is also a `utilities.h` file. ([CRAN link of npcp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/npcp/index.html))

When building the function (not inside my package) I can call that `C` function with:

```
myfunc <- function (x) {

      # Some code

  library(npcp)
  pdfsumunif <- function(x,n) {
    nx <- length(x)

    .C("pdf_sum_unif",
       as.integer(n),
       as.double(x),
       as.integer(nx),
       pdf = double(nx),
       PACKAGE = "npcp")$pdf
  }

 # More code

}
```

And all works fine. The problem happens when I try to create a package with my function. As I have to import the library in the `DESCRIPTION` file with: `Imports: npcp`, when trying to install the package with devtools I get:

```
Error in .C("pdf_sum_unif", as.integer(n), as.double(x), as.integer(nx),  : 
  "pdf_sum_unif" not available for .C() for package "npcp"
```

I tried creating a `src`file for my package, adding the `.c` and `.h` file to it, use `LinkingTo: npcp`, also tried to follow this tutorial : [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#clang), but nothing worked. Any advice?

Comment: See Writing R Extension.  The _other_ package _must_ export the function; you can then reference it.  We have examples, ie I have two packages called RApi* that export serialization and date parsing, respectively.

Comment: Following Dirk's instructions, I looked up the RApiDatetime `NAMESPACE` file which includes a directive `useDynLib(RApiDatetime, .registration=TRUE)`. From what I gather from the [useDynLib section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#useDynLib) in Writing R Extensions this is the directive that a package needs to provide in order for external code to access the functions within the package's dynamic library via `.C`/`.Call`/`.External` calls.